# find the average of 2 columns in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

would appreciate help on how to use tableau to show the average of Q1 & Q2 as shown in attached image:

[Find AvgeQ1&Q2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBDyu.png)

Comment: Nice Beattle, do you already has those data inside your Tableau or in an Excel (Access or something of a kind)?

Comment: I already have the data sample in excel but want help on how to do the same in Tableau ... any ideas? Thanks

Comment: how is the data shaped? What are the column headers in Excel? Level of detail?

Comment: CC Date Period Metric

Comment: hello, just 3 columns : CC, Date_Period, Metric  ........ the date period has the last 6 months November to April ... i need to be able to show in tableau an additional field for the average (january, april) thanks

Comment: Did you have any calculation for Jan month or it is coming from database?

Comment: hello, no calculation for January comes from the database ... thanks

Comment: Level of detail? or granularity? meaning one row per month in your data set? one row per day? one row per transaction? Ideal if you have transactional data in your data set and let Tableau generate a query to aggregate it? (If you pre-aggregate the data before making available to Tableau, you limit what you can do)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Connect --> To a File --> Excell** then open your file. If data is shown scrambled, check the checkbox located on the left of the window, below the title **Sheets --> Cleaned with data**. Then, see following image:

1 - click on top right of table field and

2 - select **Create calculated field**
[image]

3 - Find a name for the new field

4 - Enter with the expression: **SUM(([End Q1 Jan]+[End Q2 Apr])/2)**

5 - **Apply**
[image]

A new field will be created on your sheet with active calculation (if you update values on your Excell file and refresh data in Tableau - or close/open, you will see updated values).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll do better if your Date_Period column is a real date (i.e. it has all three parts - Month, Day, Year) and not just a month name or a string describing the period.

If you do that, i.e. make sure your Date_Period column has the data type date (with a calendar icon next to the field name), then drag Date_Period to the Rows shelf. You'll see it displayed as YEAR(Date_Period), meaning Tableau is extracting the Year date part and treating it as dimension. Click the + sign to the left of the field on the Rows Shelf to also get a row per QUARTER(Date_Period). Click that fields + sign to expand again to get a row per month.

Put Metric onto the text shelf on the marks card. Right click on the Metric field and choose AVG as the Measure aggregation function.

From the Analysis menu, under Totals, show Column Totals. Right click on the fields on the Rows shelf (starting from the left) and choose Subtotals to show the subtotals that you want.

If you want to change the label from Total to Average or something else to reflect the aggregation function you chose, right click on the word Total in the view and choose Format. On the Format pane, under Header, you can choose the label you wish to display

[image]